# How to connect Android to Node.js?

Tags: android, node.js, post, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to connect Android to Node.js, i have a server running in port 3000 to my localhost, when i try past data from POST method using postman, it works perfectly, but when i do the same with Android whit class HttpUrlConnection this is the result.

[Result in the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuYsR.png)

this is the code from Node.js

```
router.post('/', (req, res)=>{
  console.log(req.query);
  res.send({
    mensaje: 'I am from usuario routes'
  });
});
```

and this is from android

```
    URL obj = new URL("http://192.168.1.107:3000/");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("image", "imagen");
String data = jsonObject.toString();
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
//con.setDoInput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.getBytes().length);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
con.connect();

OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
BufferedWriter wrt = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
wrt.append(data);
wrt.flush();

wrt.close();
out.close();
con.disconnect();
```

Comment: Did you try using `con.setDoInput(true)`?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the server doesn't receive nothing, only receive the request but not data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request in Android is perfect, but in Node i was not using a middleware to convert the body, i used body-parse module and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the data before connecting to the server:

```
URL obj = new URL("http://192.168.1.107:3000/");

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("image", "imagen");
String data = jsonObject.toString();

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.getBytes().length);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter wrt = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
wrt.append(data);
wrt.flush();
wrt.close();
os.close();

con.connect();
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( .... i´m doing debug and when i do `wrt.flush()` in the next line the `wrt` still having the data ... i think the data doesn't be sending but the request yes because in the server come a empty `req.query`

Comment: @DavidSotelo I've simplified the BufferedWriter, try it now.